# Mark seam on mirror modifier blender 2.93.1

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, uv-image-editor

when I made an object with mirror modifier, and then go to edit mode select the edges to make mark seam, I didn't see apply on the mirror modifier because I'm using blender 2.93.1
anyone can tell me where can I find the apply button so the mark seam can be attached to others[! side. thanks

[image]

Comment: Click on the little rightmost downward-pointing arrow besides the cross near the top. There, in the dropdown, click 'Apply'. Note that you must be in *Object Mode* to do this

Comment: you can also select the modifier and press Ctrl A

Comment: Just because you can't see the seam marked on the mirrored side of the object doesn't mean that it hasn't been marked! If you click the leftmost hollow triangle icon at the top of the mirror modifier all the geometry on the mirrored side will be shown including your marked seam. Most people leave that option off to avoid confusion because you can't actually select or edit anything on the mirrored side even if you can see it displayed.

Comment: wow..... thank you guys, it's really helpful

Answer (score 0):

I saw apply button in the old blender version

[image]

Comment: It's been moved to a dropdown in later versions of Blender.

Comment: thank you, John this is for the first time I learn blender... The only teacher I know is that experts sharing their knowledge on youtube, and I get a good answer from masters blender in this site, makes me so excited

Comment: Glad to help! YouTube is an excellent resource for learning Blender but it's not so easy to ask questions there!